# what is the best way to record users searches and count how many times it has been queried?

Tags: sql, database

I am not sure what SQL is exactly, databases I think, would SQL be the thing to use?

I want it so that when a user types into a search box it displays a "did-you-mean" box, that also shows how many other people used that term but I will do later ;)

currently I just want the text to be saved into database (?) and also how many times it's been done.

(new to stackoverflow so sorry if format/whatever is bad)

Comment: The first thing you should clarify is what kind of application you are working on: web, desktop, mobile, ... The next thing you need to clarify is what programming language you are using to develop this application. Then we can talk about SQL :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a three table named something like `search_queries` which has columns for: `id`, `search_text`, and `count`. Everytime somebody searches just increment the `count` column where `search_text` is equal to what they searched for. This is a really broad question though and you need to start by learning the basics and report back here with more specific questions.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it if it is SQL that is what is needed